# Scroll content in SWFLoader (Flex 3)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, swfloader

I have to load huge (3000x3000) pictures in SWFLoader, and no problems with that — everything works fine. But on low resolution displays (like 1024x768) i can see only a part of picture. So i need some kind of scroll bars to scroll around a picture.

How can I do that? Please help, because i simple have no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWFLoader extends UIComponent which doesn't support Scrolling.

You can enable scrolling by nesting the SWFLoader in any Container based component, Canvas for example (its horizontalScrollPolicy & verticalScrollPolicy is set to "auto" by default)